# Best practice for button layout in responsive survey?

Tags: buttons, responsive-design, surveys, multi-step

[image]Hi everyone,

I'm designing a survey experience for a healthcare platform in which the user (often on the older side) fills out multiple surveys within a single flow.

To accommodate survey fatigue, I added a “finish later” button to the desktop design, Plus a “changes saved” indicator to mitigate anxiety of exiting a survey prematurely.

**But as you can see, all the buttons don't fit in a single row on the mobile design.** To solve for this, I suppose I could go one of three ways:

The first way would involve just eliminating the “finish later” button and “changes saved” indicator from both designs; but of course the downside is that the user doesn't have any indication that they could exit the survey aside from the “x” button on top - and with upwards of 10 surveys to complete, I am worried this will cause fatigue and drop off.

Second, I suppose I could remove those two elements from only the mobile form, but this would create the problem outlined in the first solution for mobile users, not to mention I don't even know if this is technically feasible. (We’re building this with react).

Third, I could stack the buttons vertically in the mobile version, although I anticipate that will cause issues around visual hierarchy and limited screen real estate- and again, not sure if that's even technically feasible.

Im wondering if anyone here has any experience with this dilemma who might share their insight? Or if you just have a good idea, any help is appreciated!

Comment: Is there really a need for so many buttons? Usually if the survey takes too long people don't come back to complete them. Perhaps there are better solutions to try and explore?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest responsive buttons with two-line text for small screens and an animated auto-saving alert.

[image]